# Counting rows with where clause in table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I m trying to count the rows where `SomeColumn=SomeValue`. My code is shown below. It shows nothing.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    conn.Open();
    string selectStatement = "Select count(*) from Jobs where 'JobCategory=cse'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn);
    int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    Label1.Text = count.ToString();

    conn.Close();
```

What step should I take?

Comment: I do think that a SQL `WHERE` condition enclosed in quotes will not work.

Comment: If you are changing `cse` to be a dynamic parameter, then make sure you check out how to properly pass in variables. Check out this website for a good example: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: Please tell us what is exactly not working? Do you have an exception? Did you debug your code line by line? Did you tried your query in SQL Server Management Studio? Is it getting right result? Your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single quotes are in wrong place. Try like this;

```
string selectStatement = "Select count(*) from Jobs where JobCategory = 'cse'";
```

And please parameterize your sql query always. This could be reason on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack. Here how you can use it;

```
string realcse = "Write here which value you want to filter in where clause";
string selectStatement = "Select count(*) from Jobs where JobCategory = @cse";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectStatement, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cse", realcse);
```

In your case, it should be like;

```
string realcse = "cse";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cse", realcse);
```

Comment: @user1927791 Please tell us what is exactly not working? Do you have an exception? Did you debug your code line by line?

Answer (score 1):

**Change 'JobCategory=cse' to JobCategory = 'cse'**

Like

```
string selectStatement = "Select count(*) from Jobs where JobCategory = 'cse'";
```

OR try like this

```
string selectStatement = "Select count(*) from Jobs where JobCategory Like 'cse'";
```

Check the query once in SQL before implementing it in code. Whether your getting the expected result or not check.

Answer (score 0):

```
string selectStatement = "Select COUNT(*) from [Jobs] where JobCategory='cse'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
string selectStatement = "Select  COUNT(*) as cnt from [Jobs] where JobCategory='cse'";
```